# how to handle optional parameters in a update stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to write a generic procedure that set value for one column or no of a columns in a table depending on parameters. Any idea how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by generic? It can work against any table?

Comment: sounds like you are looking to create dynamic SQL which you should carefully consider before going down that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you want something like:

```
CREATE PROC UpdateProc  
@RowID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@Parameter1 NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
@Parameter2 INT NULL

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

IF @Parameter1 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET Column1 = @Parameter1
    WHERE ID = @RowID
END

IF @Parameter2 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET Column2 = @Parameter2
    WHERE ID = @RowID
END
```

It doesn't feel particularly elegant but if you don't know/can't guarantee which parameters will be passed I don't know of a better way than to test them in turn for `NULL`.

Comment: Can I do this by using      
     @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(50) NULL, set id = ISNULL(@Parameter1, id) - 

Will it set the value to null if the parameter is passed as null

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean - can you give me a bit more info on what you're trying to do?