# Using UPDATE in stored procedure with optional parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SP like so (using SQL Server):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ClientNotes_update]
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    @ordering smallint = NULL,
    @title nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @content text = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tbl_ClientNotes
    SET ordering=@ordering, title=@title, content=@content
    WHERE id=@id
END
```

I would like to only set the values if they are passed into the SP, i.e. not NULL. Can this be done?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424244/how-to-handle-optional-parameters-in-a-update-stored-procedure) seems to suggest the only way is using completely separate queries with conditionals, but for 3 optional parameters this would obviously be a nightmare!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ClientNotes_update]
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    @ordering smallint = NULL,
    @title nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @content text = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tbl_ClientNotes
    SET ordering=ISNULL(@ordering,ordering), 
        title=ISNULL(@title,title), 
        content=ISNULL(@content, content)
    WHERE id=@id
END
```

It might also be worth adding an extra part to the `WHERE` clause, if you use transactional replication then it will send another update to the subscriber if all are NULL, to prevent this.

```
WHERE id=@id AND (@ordering IS NOT NULL OR
                  @title IS NOT NULL OR
                  @content IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Coalesce() is best practice, not IsNull()

Comment: It is not best practice, that is you subjective preference as `COALESCE` is ANSI. Both functions act differently, to say that you should always use one over the other as best practice is wrong. But in this case they act the same.

Comment: @chris Actually, `ISNULL` is correct here because any of those fields could be nullable. If the parameter in the stored procedure is null, and the current value for the field is also null, you will get an error for not providing at least one non-null value to the `COALESCE` function.

So yes, you were correct in using `ISNULL`, but they do not act the same in this case.

Comment: @Noah i've just checked this out, the error you get from `COALESCE(NULL, NULL)` is that one of the arguments must be a typed null. A subtle difference. As the parameters are typed it should be fine. If you do `DECLARE @test INT = NULL; SELECT COALESCE(@test, NULL) then it doesn't throw an error as `@test` is an `INT`. The way the two infer the return types are different which is one of the reasons why the behavior is different. MSDN has quite a bit of detail on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: I got a question, if I have Null values is it required to identify the field as null in order to update it?

Comment: also could you provide code for using C# in executing the stored procedure

Comment: What if you want to set value of one of the columns to NULL?

Comment: @ile then you would just use the SQL in the question. This question is specifically asking how to avoid setting the column value when the parameter is NULL.

Comment: if before Title not null, and now I want update Title to null. With this code I never update Title to null

Comment: @PhuocLe correct, but the question specifically asks to only update the Title if it is NOT NULL

Answer (score 3):

```
   UPDATE tbl_ClientNotes
    SET 
      ordering=ISNULL@ordering,ordering), 
      title=isnull(@title,title), 
      content=isnull(@content,content)
    WHERE id=@id
```

I think I remember seeing before that if you are updating to the same value SQL Server will actually recognize this and won't do an unnecessary write.

Answer (score 3):

One Idea:

```
UPDATE tbl_ClientNotes
SET ordering=ISNULL(@ordering, ordering), 
    title=ISNULL(@title, title),  
    content=ISNULL(@content, content)
WHERE id=@id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl_ClientNotes 
SET ordering=@ordering, title=@title, content=@content 
WHERE id=@id 
AND @ordering IS NOT NULL
AND @title IS NOT NULL
AND @content IS NOT NULL
```

Or if you meant you only want to update individual columns you would use the post above mine. I read it as do not update if any values are null

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE LN
    (
    @Firstname nvarchar(200)
)

AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE tbl_Students1
    SET Firstname=@Firstname 

    WHERE Studentid=3
END


exec LN 'Thanvi'
```